# why my self-defined layer failed in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

error message:
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: (None, 3). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

can anyone help me about this error, i think i define this layer quite similar with dense layer, why it doesnt work?

my layer code:

```
from keras.layers.core import Layer
from keras.engine import InputSpec
from keras import backend as K
try:
from keras import initializations
except ImportError:
from keras import initializers as initializations

import numpy as np
class HardAttention(Layer):
def init(self, **kwargs):
super(HardAttention, self).init(**kwargs)
self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2)

def build(self, input_shape):
    input_dim = input_shape[-1]
    self.attention = self.add_weight(shape=input_shape,
                                     initializer='uniform',
                                     name='attention',
                                     dtype=np.float32,
                                     trainable=True)
                                     #dtype=bool)
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(min_ndim=2, axes={-1: input_dim})
    self.built = True
    super(HardAttention, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs):
    return K.multiply(inputs, self.attention)

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape
```

model code:

```
(time_step, n_stock) = np.shape(x_train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(HardAttention())
model.add(Dense(5))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a Layer with the name of `Input`. Not import InputLayer from engine.

The following snippet works in Colab (tf 1.4).

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras import backend as K

import numpy as np

class HardAttention(Layer):
  def init(self, **kwargs):
    super(HardAttention, self).init(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    input_dim = input_shape[-1]
    self.attention = self.add_weight(shape=input_shape,
                                     initializer='uniform',
                                     name='attention',
                                     dtype=np.float32,
                                     trainable=True)
                                     #dtype=bool)
    self.built = True
    super(HardAttention, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs):
    return K.multiply(inputs, self.attention)

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return input_shape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(3,)))
model.add(HardAttention())
model.add(Dense(5))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
```